# Cross platform variadic macro with 0..n parameters

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c-preprocessor, template-meta-programming

For a parameter pack I need a macro which can take any number of parameters (types actually), which works cross platform. This code works nicely with GCC, LLVM and MSVC (after the preprocessor had been reworked to [support the `##` sequence](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/msvc-preprocessor-progress-towards-conformance/) (see Behavior 4 [comma elision in variadic macros]
):

```
class A {};
class B: A {};
class C: A {};
class D: A {};

template<typename... Interfaces>
class Aggregator: public Interfaces... {
};

#define INNER(...) typedef Aggregator<__VA_ARGS__> AGG;
#define ENVIRONMENT(...) INNER(B, C, ## __VA_ARGS__)

ENVIRONMENT(D)
```

The problem here is the empty-parameters case (`ENVIRONMENT()`). As I cannot use C++20 yet (which comes with the [`__VA_OPT__()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/preprocessor/replace) token sequence, I have to find a solution that requires at most C++17. GCC + LLVM have no problem with an empty parameter list, however MSVC insists on at least one parameter for the comma elision to work.

What is required to make this construct also work fully with MSVC?

### Update:

It turns out the empty-parameter case doesn't work for GCC either: https://godbolt.org/z/1zKZO- .

Comment: "*GCC + LLVM have no problem with an empty parameter list*" - [they actually do have a problem](https://godbolt.org/z/A-qDQ5), unless compiled with gnu++ mode. This particular example could probably utilize variadic alias template.

Comment: Interesting, seems I need to do more tests specifically with GCC, however I have seen quite a few solutions with the token pasting sequence that didn't mention the GNU extension requirement. With (Apple) LLVM 10 (not using GNU extensions) it compiles without any warning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an approach that actually does what you asked for... I've predefined this to work with MSVC, gcc, and clang (to work with just gcc and clang, or just MSVC, would be simpler).

This implements `OPTIONAL`, which expects a tuple (parenthesized tokens) as the first argument.  When `OPTIONAL` is called with just an empty second argument, it expands to nothing; otherwise, it will expand to the unwrapped version of the first argument.  The end result is a kind of *analog* to (but certainly not *equivalent* to) C++20's `__VA_OPT__`.

The following is the `OPTIONAL` implementation, and support macros:

```
#define GLUE(A,B) GLUE_C(GLUE_I,(A,B))
#define GLUE_C(A,B) A B
#define GLUE_I(A,B) A##B
#define FIRST(...) FIRST_C(FIRST_I,(__VA_ARGS__,))
#define FIRST_C(A,B) A B
#define FIRST_I(X,...) X
#define THIRD(...) THIRD_C(THIRD_CC,(THIRD_I,(__VA_ARGS__,,,)))
#define THIRD_C(A,B) A B
#define THIRD_CC(A,B) A B
#define THIRD_I(A,B,C,...) C
#define COUNT(...) COUNT_C(COUNT_I,(__VA_ARGS__,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,))
#define COUNT_C(A,B) A B
#define COUNT_I(_,_9,_8,_7,_6,_5,_4,_3,_2,X,...) X
#define DISCARD_ARGUMENTS(...)
#define OPTIONAL(APPLY_,...) \
   THIRD(GLUE(OPTIONAL_SHIFT_IF_1_IS_,COUNT(__VA_ARGS__)),\
         OPTIONAL_SINGLE_CASE,\
         APPLY_OPTION) \
   (APPLY_,__VA_ARGS__)
#define OPTIONAL_SHIFT_IF_1_IS_1 ,
#define OPTIONAL_SINGLE_CASE(APPLY_,...) \
   THIRD(OPTIONAL_SHIFT_TEST __VA_ARGS__ (0_UNLOCK), \
         DISCARD_ARGUMENTS, \
         APPLY_OPTION)(APPLY_,)
#define OPTIONAL_SHIFT_TEST(...) GLUE(OPTIONAL_APPLY_SHIFT_TEST_,FIRST(__VA_ARGS__))
#define OPTIONAL_APPLY_SHIFT_TEST_0_UNLOCK ,

#define APPLY_OPTION(A,...) APPLY_OPTION_C(APPLY_OPTION_I,A)
#define APPLY_OPTION_C(A,B) A B
#define APPLY_OPTION_I(...) __VA_ARGS__
```

The core mechanism is an "indirect third macro"; the idea here is to generate a first argument that applies some "test" which, if something of interest shows up, generates a comma, which shifts the second argument to the third position just prior to selection.

This is used twice by `OPTIONAL`; if there's one argument, there's a next stage test to see if that argument has no tokens.  This test injects the argument's tokens between `OPTIONAL_SHIFT_TEST` and `(0_UNLOCK)`; if there are no tokens, that makes a call, and this macro will generate an object macro that creates the shifting comma.  This indirection is intentional, allowing parentheses to be in the first argument without a false detection (see demo).

> What is required to make this construct also work fully with MSVC?

...built into the indirection layers of all macros are "caller macros"; here, they all have `_C` in the name, take two parameters `A` and `B`, and simply expand to `A B`; their use is always to separate a macro name from a macro argument set.  *Those* address MSVC.  Were I actually trying to *target* MSVC (for whatever reason), only one such caller would be necessary; by making a caller for each macro set, however, we get to make this work for MSVC *and* gcc/clang as well.  (ETA: `THIRD` requires two caller indirections; once for the varying arguments in third itself, and the other to properly interpret the expanded first argument's commas, since that's the whole point of the `THIRD` macro).

Note that this doesn't rely on any of the compiler specific comma elision tricks.

Finally... with `OPTIONAL` in place, all you need to do is this:

```
#define INNER(...) typedef Aggregator<__VA_ARGS__> AGG;
#define ENVIRONMENT(...) INNER(B, C OPTIONAL((,),__VA_ARGS__) __VA_ARGS__)
```

Godbolt demos

- gcc/clang: https://godbolt.org/z/GK3Huh
- MSVC: https://godbolt.org/z/kvRPau

Answer (score 0):

what about something like this?

```
template <class... X>
using INNER = Aggregator<B, C, X...>;

#define ENVIRONMENT(...) typedef INNER<__VA_ARGS__> AGG

ENVIRONMENT(); // Or ENVIRONMENT(D)
```

Hope this helps...